# product image size folder issue

Tags: image

I am using this code to store particular product image size in my own different folder. but it is storing all the size images in "p1" folder.my image width is 500 and height could be any should be store in p1/c/ . another is width with 280 and height any should be save in p2/c/.

any solution for this?

```
 if(($this->_width == 500) || (!empty($this->_height))) 
    {

    $path = array(
          //  Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_media_config')->getBaseMediaPath(),
         Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_media_config'),
           // 'cache',
          //  Mage::app()->getStore()->getId(),
            $path[] = 'p1/C:' // $this->getDestinationSubdir()
        );

}  
elseif(($this->_width == 280) || (!empty($this->_height)))
{

       $path = array(
          //  Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_media_config')->getBaseMediaPath(),
         Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_media_config'),
           // 'cache',
          //  Mage::app()->getStore()->getId(),
            $path[] = 'p2/C:' // $this->getDestinationSubdir()
        ); 
}

else
{

   $path = array(
          //  Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_media_config')->getBaseMediaPath(),
         Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_media_config'),
           // 'cache',
          //  Mage::app()->getStore()->getId(),
            $path[] = 'R/C:' // $this->getDestinationSubdir()
        ); 

}
```

Comment: Programming style: beware that this usage of curly braces can be problematic with JavaScript http://encosia.com/in-javascript-curly-brace-placement-matters-an-example/

Answer (score 0):

I think your conditionals are wrong, you don't need the `!empty($this->_height)` part if you don't care about height, if I have understood what you want

So, it should be...

```
if ($this->_width == 500) {
    ...
} elseif ($this->_width == 280) {
    ...
} else {
    ...
}
```

Comment: its not working for me..any other solution

Comment: In that case, please edit your post & clean your code to make it readable. Error should be there